# How to use "We do not [list of items]" with "nor" suffix for emphasis correctly

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

I have a sentence of the form:

"We do not [action1], [action2], nor do we [action3]"
example: "We do not eat apples, pick oranges, nor do we care for pears."

Is this grammatically correct? How should I use the nor at the end for emphasis?

Comment: "We do not eat apples, nor pick oranges, nor care for pears."

Comment: Isn't this like using "and" when listing things? "I got myself a car, and a key, and a hat, and a chair"... It's too verbose, I prefer "I got myself a car, a key, a hat, and a chair"

Comment: OK - We do not eat apples, pick oranges, or care for pears. I do not swear, smoke, gamble, drink alcohol, or read dirty books.

Comment: Ok cool, I guess "nor" is not the correct choice here, but in what case should I use it?

Comment: You can follow 'neither' or 'not' with a list separated by 'nor' or alternatively, with a list separated by commas and 'or' before the last item. The multiple 'nor' version adds emphasis and rhythm. Example from Dover Beach, a poem by Matthew Arnold _...the world, which seems
To lie before us like a land of dreams,
So various, so beautiful, so new,
Hath really neither joy, nor love, nor light,
Nor certitude, nor peace, nor help for pain;_

Comment: That is like using 'and' for emphasis - "You are handsome _and_ wise  _and_ good _and_ kind _and_ a good dancer" said my wife.

Comment: @justsomeesldude In the original sentence in the question, if you don't want to repeat *nor*, you would need to use *neither* instead, as well as a second clause. *We do not eat apples or pick oranges; neither do we care for pears.*